# In Linux, How do you automatically run commands with custom parameters you feed it on SSH login?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, parameters, scripting

This question:

https://superuser.com/questions/355029/linux-how-to-automatically-run-commands-on-ssh-login#355030

Only tells me how to run static commands. What it does not tell me is how I can feed it parameters. So say for example, I would like something like this to happen:

```
$ ssh boat@programming.com -p 2222 --parameter1 "boat programming"
Last login: Sat Dec 10 03:59:37 2016 from some place
boat programming

# .bashrc executes something like this:
echo $parameter1
```

If I have to use a language like `expect`, fine, but ideally I would like to keep this straightforward and simple.

Comment: @EricRenouf No; I'll be scripting this with a `#!/bin/bash` script. I tried doing what you said, having an auto ssh login followed by an echo command, however the command only executed after I exited my ssh session.

Answer (score 1):

Save this short script (on your remote system) with name `run` in a directory which is part of your `$PATH` variable (on your remote system) and make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$2"
```

Use it this way:

```
ssh boat@programming.com -p 2222 run --parameter1 "'boat programming'"
```

Output:

```
boat programming
```

Comment: I am having some issues getting this to execute. I made the executable on my remote system, placed the script in one of the $path's (`/home/akiva/bin`) but i'm getting this error regardless: `bash: run: command not found`

Comment: I looked at it; my presumption is that certain `$PATH`'s will not work. However, providing a full absolute path did work. I also think that `--parameter1` is more misleading than useful, as that will count as a parameter itself. I am trying to think of a way to qualify that parameter.

Comment: I suppose it does not work in directories which added to your `$PATH` variable by your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. It works for me when I move `run` to `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

The way, in theory, to do this is to put `parameter1` in your environment, and let the remote process inherit it from `ssh`.

```
$ parameter1="boat programming" ssh boat@programming.com -p 2222
```

In practice, this probably will not work, because it requires the remote `sshd` agent to be running with the `PermitUserEnvironment` option enable, which is not true by default.

The only way to force this would be to run `bash` explicitly on the remote host with the appropriate environment.

```
$ ssh boat@programming.com -p 2222 'parameter1="boat programming" bash -i'
```

Comment: I'm playing around with your method as we speak. I'll let you know if I have any success, and accept if I do.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the first line would work; I know `ssh` will consult `~/.ssh/environment` for assignments to use on the remote end if `sshd` allows; I'm only guessing that it exports the local in-memory environment as well.

Comment: `sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no boat@programming.com -p 2222 parameter1="'happy day'" /home/akiva/bin/run` -- can confirm that this works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution:

0) If you want to automate password entry (Completely optional):

```
sudo apt install sshpass
```

---

1) SSH into your server, and create a file called `run`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $parameter1
```

---

2) Make it executable

```
chmod +x run
```

---

3) Handle the parameters like this (Concatenate these lines.):

*Avoid manual input of the password. (Be Careful!)*

`sshpass -p "$YOURPASSWORD"`

*Standard SSH login*

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no boat@programming.com -p 2222`

*Parameters must go first. Use single quotes within double quotes otherwise `day` will be returned as an unknown command error:* 
`parameter1="'happy day'"`

Give an absolute path to the program you wrote.
`/path/to/run`

Alltogether:

```
 sshpass -p "$YOURPASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no boat@programming.com -p 2222 parameter1="'happy day'" /path/to/run
```